# How do I correctly handle possibly harmful links to malware in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

*Be advised, the link in the question below might be harmful (not these links, obviously).*

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627477/how-to-prevent-malware-to-modify-the-window-location
Edit reject: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7682823

The question names malware in its title, and the second sentence in that question is a link to a site possibly containing said malware. Whether this is really the case or not, I couldn't say. I didn't click it to find out.

I saw the question and figured I'll quickly edit out the link, as it might be a potential risk and it didn't really serve any purpose. But my edit was rejected, and the question is now "on hold" with the link still being there.

If this link was harmful or not is not really the point here. What if it is/was? I thought a quick edit would at least get a potentially harmful link off the front-page, before a vote to delete or a flag for moderator would take over.

Since my edit was rejected, I assume my action was not correct. What's the correct way to handle this? And also, was my urgency in this matter a bit over-dramatic? Perhaps this was nothing to worry about at all...

*Edit: Maybe I'm not understanding the accept/reject mechanics properly. As I interpreted it, the OP rejected my edit, and someone else approved this rejection. Might not have gone down like that, hmm.*

Comment: I think, you're not the only one who has spotted this link as potentially dangerous. So, the people here are smart enough to avoid such links. Anyone can edit practically anything he wants. If your edit was rejected, it doesn't mean it was wrong. It means the author of this question _thought it was incorrect_. On the other hand, this link is the evidence, so anyone can click and get malware as the OP probably did :)

Comment: It seems to me that the post (now deleted) was pretty clear that clicking on the link could lead to being redirected to a site with malware. I mean, the question literally says "the following site spreads malware". So I'm not sure how important it would be to remove that link. Ironically though, the link you deleted isn't really the problematic one (assuming any link is problematic). You left intact the bit.ly URL (granted, not an actual link), to which the first page redirects, and which the OP describes as the URL that actually leads to malware.

Comment: As far as the review mechanic goes: if I read the log correctly, one other person voted to approve your edit. Four such votes would be needed for the edit to take effect, but before any more people could vote to approve the edit, the OP voted to reject it. Since they are the author of the post in question, their vote trumps any other approval votes.